# Islands as Coastal Spaces

Tags: tales-of-arabian-nights

**Do Islands count as Coastal spaces?**

One specific effect in the game makes reference to *coastal spaces*, which do not appear to have a clear definition or specific terrain icon.  Do islands count for this purpose?  By definition, islands are surrounded by coast and thus contain coast; however, they are not part of the coast of any mainland continent or landmass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes most islands count as coastal spaces, not because they are islands, but because of the definition of coastal space in Tales of the Arabian Nights. I don't have the rule book on hand at the moment, but from what I remember **a coastal space is defined as any non-sea space with a water route leaving it.**

This definition would match most but not all island spaces as coastal (notably the one south of P'an P'an, which connects only to P'an P'an).

Comment: This is inevitably the conclusion my gaming group came to, and I forgot to answer my own question.  Thanks for adding an answer to an old question.

Answer (score 2):

Barring any rules to the contrary, coastal is generally interpreted as "next to water", so I would say that an island certainly counts for this.